# How does a 10 second delay after switching on the APU BLEED prevent an engine stall while carrying out a one engine taxi on departure in the A320?

Tags: airbus-a320, taxiing, single-engine

My question mainly pertains to the delay of 10 seconds. As per the A320 FCOM when performing a one engine taxi at departure before starting engine 2 a 10 second delay has to be catered for after switching on the APU BLEED. The reason mentioned in the FCOM is as follows:

"Wait 10 s before the ENG 2 start, in order to ensure that the BLEED system valves are no longer in transit. This time delay will prevent ENG 1 stall"

How does the time delay prevent eng 1 stall is what I can't understand. Attached is a picture of the official FCOM excerpt. [image]

Comment: I'm not A320 qualified – but bleed air valves are often electrically driven but pneumatically operated. Depending on available bleed air the valves need some time to close or open. As you just configured the bleed air system to use APU bleed air to start the engine, the eng #1 bleed valve might not have closed yet. An engine start has a high air demand and therefore might extract too much bleed air from eng #1 with might lead to engine stall. The 10s wait time makes sure that the eng #1 bleed air valve has closed and you don't run into trouble there. As said – I'm not A320 rated, it is a guess

Comment: As stated in the quoted material it’s not the time delay that prevents stall- it’s the bleed valves being in transit that could lead to stall. Your real question is therefore “How would attempting a #2 start with the bleed valves in transit lead to a #1 engine stall?”

Comment: @Jim why dont you Formulare an answer on this insight